# haskell function to identify triangles

Tags: haskell

i am brand new to haskell and have been asked by one of my professors to make a simple haskell program that determines if a triangle is valid by the three angles provided by the users, and to identify if the triangle is right obtuse or scalene. i am struggling to understand how variables (particularly numbers) work in haskell and am trying to at least complete the function that determines validity my code looks like this,

```
main = do
    let angle1 = 0
    let angle2 = 0 
    let angle3 = 0
    putStrLn "input your angles."
    angle1 <- getLine
    angle2 <- getLine
    angle3 <- getLine
    if angle1 + angle2 + angle3 == 180
        then putStrLn "triangle is valid"
    else putStrLn "triangle is not valid"
```

i assume it has to do with IO errors or that getline is string instead of int? any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the type of `getLine`?

Comment: What is the type of `+`?

Comment: Binding variables to `0` like that isn't useful at all. Remember: Haskell variables are immutable, so once you define them to be something, you can never change them. The later bindings will actually *shadow* the original ones, binding *different* variables that just happen to have the same names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `getLine` reads strings, but you actually need numbers. The smallest fix is to switch to `readLn :: Read a => IO a`.

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Input your angles."
  angle1 <- readLn
  angle2 <- readLn
  angle3 <- readLn
  if angle1 + angle2 + angle3 == 180
    then putStrLn "The triangle is valid."
    else putStrLn "The triangle is not valid."
  -- Add right triangle logic here. You
  -- may wish to use the `any` function.
```

Comment: while this helped me compile (which i greatly appreciate) it still errors out past insertion of my first number

Comment: @Clambert, what did you type? What error did you get exactly?

Comment: sorry it was errors specific to the fact i was using an online compiler, after using a regular compiler it ran perfectly and helped me to finish the program thanks!